# Assign array's values at compile time with and enum as index (C++)

Tags: c++, enums, constexpr, compile-time, array-initialization

I'm trying to use a C-style array as a map through enums but I can't initialize arrays by parts...  I'll explain myself better through code:
I have something like:

```
enum Objects{CAR = 0, PLANE, BOY};
```

I have:

```
static const char* texturePaths[] = {"..\\car.png", "..\\plane.png", "..\\boy.png"};
```

and that actually works the way I want, i.e.

```
initTexture(texturePaths[CAR]);
```

but in this way I **must to** make sure that I'm declaring in the **same order** both enum and array.
I'd like to do something like this:

```
enum Objects{CAR = 0, PLANE, BOY, size};
const char* texturePaths[Objects::size];
texturePaths[BOY] = "..\\boy.png";
texturePAths[CAR] = "..\\car.png";
...
```

I know that could work, but I need to do it inside a function and call it, so run time. I want to do it at compile time because there are constant values that will never change and it's a waste to do it at run time.
I also know that **`constexpr`** could do it through lambda functions, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: `CAR = 0` by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tagged `constexpr`, so you can use C++11 or newer, so you can use `std::array`.
Generic suggestion: use `std::array`, when possible, instead old C-style arrays.

> I want to so it at compile time

If you accept a C++17 solution (?) you can use the fact that the not-const version of `operator[]` for `std::array` is (starting from C++17) `constexpr`.

So you can create a `constexpr` function to initialize the `std::array` as you want

```
enum Objects{CAR = 0, PLANE, BOY, size};

constexpr auto getTexturePath ()
 {
   std::array<char const *, Objects::size>  ret {{}};

   ret[BOY] = "..\\boy.png";
   ret[CAR] = "..\\car.png";
   // ...

   return ret;
 }
```

and save the result in a `constexpr` (important!) variable

```
   constexpr auto texturePath { getTexturePath() };
```

The following is a full compiling C++17 example with some `static_assert()` as proof that the initialization of `texturePath` is done compile-time.

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

enum Objects{CAR = 0, PLANE, BOY, size};

constexpr auto getTexturePath ()
 {
   std::array<char const *, Objects::size>  ret {{}};

   ret[BOY] = "..\\boy.png";
   ret[CAR] = "..\\car.png";
   // ...

   return ret;
 }

int main()
 {
   constexpr auto texturePath { getTexturePath() };

   static_assert( texturePath[CAR][3] == 'c' ); 
   static_assert( texturePath[CAR][4] == 'a' ); 
   static_assert( texturePath[CAR][5] == 'r' ); 
 }
```